# NetSuite - Fields are not being set in the sales order after I set context to 'scheduled'

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Hope you can assist.
I am currently trying to conduct one of the most simplest tasks via a user event script - that is to set a new value in the 'discount rate' field on the sales order. My script works fine when testing it on the client, but when the scheduled script is triggered, the field fails to set/update.

The following code is within a 'beforesubmit' operation. Can you spot what I have done wrong?

```
function beforeSubmit_discountVAT(type){

if(nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext() !='scheduled')
    return;

  var getDiscountVal = nlapiGetFieldValue('discountrate');
  var correctDiscount = getDiscountVal / 1.2;
  nlapiSetFieldValue('discountrate', correctDiscount);
}
```

In short - All i want to do is deduct the discount value by 20%. Can you use 'nlapiSetFieldValue' when a user event script is triggered from a scheduled script?

Thanks in advance.

AWB

Answer (score 2):

When editing an existing record, `nlapiSetFieldValue` cannot be used in a Before Load event on fields that are stored with the record. From the function's JSDocs:

> Sets the value of a given body field. This API can be used in user event beforeLoad scripts to initialize field on new records or non-stored fields.

`nlapiSetFieldValue` can thus only be used reliably in Before Load on new records or non-stored fields.

Realizing this is a month old so you've probably found a solution, I would move your code to the Before Submit event. I tested this using a Scheduled Script:

```
var customer = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', '31294');
nlapiSubmitRecord(customer);
```

and User Event on the Customer record, Before Submit event:

```
if (nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext() === 'scheduled') {
    nlapiSetFieldValue('url', 'http://www.google.com/', false);
}
```

This works as expected for me in a 2013.1 Sandbox environment.

Using `nlapiSubmitField` in After Submit as mentioned in the other answer is an unnecessarily long operation that will use extra governance units. Not a huge deal if that's the only thing your script is doing, but if you ever expand the script or add looping, it can add up quickly in terms of performance and governance usage.

Also, it may not be necessary, but you should ensure that `getDiscountVal` is a `Number` by doing:

```
var getDiscountVal = parseInt(nlapiGetFieldValue('discountrate'), 10);
```

If it comes back as a `String` then your division operation may give a strange result which may also cause `nlapiSetFieldValue` to fail or set the field to an odd value.

Answer (score 0):

two suggestions

- Make sure that your script is being executed by adding a few nlapiLogExecution statements
- Instead of doing it in beforesubmit, change this field in aftersubmit function using nlapiSubmitField

Answer (score 0):

"*Can you use 'nlapiSetFieldValue' when a user event script is triggered from a scheduled script?*"

Yeah Absolutely yes.Context is also correct its scheduled.

Please make sure that you are submitting the record nlapiSubmitRecord(recordObj) at the end.

If you are not comfortable with nlapiSubmitRecord() you can obviously use nlapiSubmitField()

If still you get stuck up then please paste the complete code so that we could assist you.

Cheers!!!